# Get GeoJSON Features using Mapbox?

Tags: web-mapping, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'm using Mapbox to create webmapping, I want to get GeoJSON Features. I tried `map.queryRenderedFeatures` but it returns array empty.
there are my code:

```
map.on('load', function(e) {
map.addSource("places", {
    "type": "geojson",
    "data": "data/polygon.geojson"
});

map.addLayer({
    "id": "Surfaces",
    "type": "fill",
    "source": "places",
    "sources-layer": "layer",
    "layout": {},
    "paint": {
        "fill-color": "#088",
        "fill-opacity": 0.8
    }
});

var feature = map.queryRenderedFeatures({ layers: ['Surfaces'] });
console.log(feature);
})
```

Comment: I found the same bug, return array length are always 0, [] empty array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `querySourceFeatures` which return all geojson features within a layer if no filter is applied.

```
var features = map.querySourceFeatures('your_layer_id');
```

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#querysourcefeatures

But you may check first that the layer is fully loaded, or you will get an empty array.

```
map.on("sourcedata", function(e) {
    if (map.getSource('your_layer_id') && map.isSourceLoaded('your_layer_id')) {
        console.log('source loaded!');
        var features = map.querySourceFeatures('your_layer_id');
        console.log(features);
    }
});
```

Source about the event: [Mapbox GL JS - "Source Loaded" event](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240134/mapbox-gl-js-source-loaded-event)

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve all data although these are clustered?

Comment: This only returns the source features within the viewport boundaries :  _this function does not check tiles outside the currently visible viewport._.  How can we get ALL the source features ?

Comment: Problem also is, this returns the internal mapboxGL representation featuring a `_geometry` attribute instead of a `geometry`, including attributes not present in the geoJson standard, such as `_vectorTileFeature`

Answer (score -1):

share my working sample:

you must use 
               map.queryRenderedFeatures(

```
                      { layers: ['lineString-line'] }
```

with

```
           map.on("sourcedata", function(e) {
```

Otherwise, you will always get 0 empty feature.

```
 // map.queryRenderedFeatures({ layers: ['point-circle'] });
// always return [] empty 0, which should not
// reason is map.addlayer take a few second, have not finish render
// you have to wait until all tiles finish render, to use 
// map.queryRenderedFeatures({ layers: ['point-circle'] });
// this is how, 

//map.on("sourcedataloading", function(e) {  // not work, not fired
//https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#queryrenderedfeatures



map.on("sourcedata", function(e) {


        // without this, will have many many event fired.
        if (map.areTilesLoaded()) 
        {

            console.log('at least one Tiles loaded!');



            if (typeof map.getLayer('lineString-line') !== 'undefined') {
              // Remove map layer & source.
             // map.removeLayer('route').removeSource('route');

                    var _line_layer = map.queryRenderedFeatures(

                      { layers: ['lineString-line'] }

                      ); 
              console.log('_line_layer -> (((', _line_layer.length)
            }



            if (typeof map.getLayer('polygon-fill') !== 'undefined') {
                         var _polygon_layer = map.queryRenderedFeatures(

                        //  { layers: ['polygon-borders-line'] }
                           { layers: ['polygon-fill'] } 
                          );
                          console.log('_polygon_layer -> (((', _polygon_layer.length)
                        }  


           if (typeof map.getLayer('point-circle') !== 'undefined') {
                    var _point_layer = map.queryRenderedFeatures(

                              { layers: ['point-circle'] }

                              );



                    console.log('_point_layer -> (((', _point_layer.length)
           }




        }// if

      }); // map.on("sourcedata"
```